# react-native: upload to s3 Access Denied - only from app

Tags: node.js, react-native, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image to S3 directly from my app using an IAM role, currently with full S3 access. These keys work from the command line, and also from a node script using the exact same code as the in-app code. But when the app tries to upload, `Access Denied` is always returned.

```
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
const fs = require('fs');


let bucket = new S3({
    secretAccessKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    accessKeyId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    Bucket: "app-uploads",
});

const buf = fs.readFileSync('./test.jpg');

var params = {
  Key: 'image.jpg',
  Body: buf,
  ContentEncoding: 'base64',
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  Bucket: "app-uploads",
};


bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!');
    }
});
```